# JavaScript изменение стиля кнопки после отправки в файле FormValidation

Tags: javascript

##### 1 вопрос

После добавления новой карточки, когда хочешь добавить новую карточку, то кнопка "Создать" визуально становится активной, но по факту неактивна. Как можно добавить для нее стиль, чтоб она становилась визуально неактивной после добавления новой карточки?

https://alexfinokhin.github.io/Mesto-project/

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 hasInvalidInput = (inputList) => {
    return inputList.some((inputElement) => {
      return !inputElement.validity.valid;
    });
  };
  
  function toggleButtonState(inputList, buttonElement, inactiveButtonClass) {
    if (hasInvalidInput(inputList)) {
      buttonElement.setAttribute("disabled", true);
      buttonElement.classList.add(inactiveButtonClass);
    } else {
      buttonElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
      buttonElement.classList.remove(inactiveButtonClass);
    }
  }
```

Набросал такой код, ориентируясь на похожие случаи, но у меня никак не получается адаптировать его под свой код. Не понимаю, как его можно вставить, не поломав весь код. Ну либо он совсем не подходит под мой код и я ошибаюсь

FormValidation код:

```
const checkInputValidity = (
  formElement,
  inputElement,
  inputErrorClass,
  errorClass
) => {
  if (inputElement.validity.valid) {
    hideInputError(formElement, inputElement, inputErrorClass, errorClass);
  } else {
    showInputError(
      formElement,
      inputElement,
      inputElement.validationMessage,
      inputErrorClass,
      errorClass
    );
  }
};

const showInputError = (
  formElement,
  inputElement,
  errorMessage,
  inputErrorClass,
  errorClass
) => {
  if (!inputElement) return;
  inputElement.classList.add(inputErrorClass);
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`#${inputElement.id}-error`);
  if (!errorElement) return;
  errorElement.classList.add(errorClass);
  errorElement.textContent = errorMessage;
};

const hideInputError = (
  formElement,
  inputElement,
  inputErrorClass,
  errorClass
) => {
  if (!inputElement) return;
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`#${inputElement.id}-error`);
  inputElement.classList.remove(inputErrorClass);
  if (!errorElement) return;
  errorElement.classList.remove(errorClass);
  errorElement.textContent = "";
};

const toggleButtonState = (formElement, buttonElement, inactiveButtonClass) => {
  const isFormValid = formElement && formElement.checkValidity();
  buttonElement.classList.toggle(inactiveButtonClass, !isFormValid);
  buttonElement.disabled = !isFormValid;
};



const setEventListeners = (
  formElement,
  {
    inputSelector,
    submitButtonSelector,
    inactiveButtonClass,
    inputErrorClass,
    errorClass,
  }
) => {
  const inputList = Array.from(formElement.querySelectorAll(inputSelector));
  const buttonElement = formElement.querySelector(submitButtonSelector);

 

  toggleButtonState(formElement, buttonElement, inactiveButtonClass);
  inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
    inputElement.addEventListener("input", () => {
      checkInputValidity(
        formElement,
        inputElement,
        inputErrorClass,
        errorClass
      );
      toggleButtonState(formElement, buttonElement, inactiveButtonClass);
    });
  });
};

const enableValidation = ({ formSelector, ...rest }) => {
  const getFormList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(formSelector));
   getFormList.forEach((formElement) => {setEventListeners(formElement, rest); });
};

enableValidation({
  formSelector: ".popup__form",
  inputSelector: ".popup__input",
  submitButtonSelector: ".popup__save-button",
  inactiveButtonClass: "popup__save-button_disabled",
  inputErrorClass: "popup__input-error",
  errorClass: "popup__input-error_active",
});
```

Index.js код:

```
const popups = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");
const popupEditProfile = document.querySelector(".popup_form_edit");
const popupAddCard = document.querySelector(".popup_type_add-card");
const typeAddCard = document.querySelector(".popup_type_add-card");
const profileName = document.querySelector(".profile__name");
const profileJob = document.querySelector(".profile__job");
const profileForm = document.querySelector(".popup__form_profile");
const profileNameInput = document.querySelector("#nameInput");
const profileJobInput = document.querySelector("#jobInput");
const editButton = document.querySelector(".profile__edit-button");
const imgPopup = document.querySelector(".popup_viewer");
const titlePopup = imgPopup.querySelector(".popup__text");
const cardsContainer = document.querySelector(".elements__list");
const templateCard = document.querySelector(".template-card").content;
const typePlace = document.querySelector("#typePlace");
const typeUrl = document.querySelector("#typeUrl");
const popupActiveClass = "popup_opened";

function addCardListeners(card, cardData) {
  card
    .querySelector(".element__like-button")
    .addEventListener("click", activeLikeBtn);
  card
    .querySelector(".element__trash-button")
    .addEventListener("click", deleteCard);
  card.querySelector(".element__image").addEventListener("click", () => {
    openPopupCardShow(cardData);
  });
}

const formAddNewCard = popupAddCard.querySelector(".popup__form");
const buttonPlace = formAddNewCard.querySelector(".popup__save-button");
formAddNewCard.addEventListener("submit", addCard);

function createCard(data) {
  const newCard = templateCard.querySelector(".element").cloneNode(true);
  const elementImage = newCard.querySelector(".element__image");

  elementImage.src = data.link;
  elementImage.alt = data.name;

  newCard.querySelector(".element__name").textContent = data.name;
  buttonPlace.disabled = true;
  addCardListeners(newCard, data);
 
  return newCard;
}

function addTemplateCard(data) {
  const cardClone = createCard(data);
  cardsContainer.prepend(cardClone);
}

function addCard(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  const cardName = typePlace.value;
  const cardLink = typeUrl.value;
  addTemplateCard({ name: cardName, link: cardLink });
  event.target.reset();
  hidePopup(popupAddCard);
  buttonPlace.disabled = true;
  
}

initialCards.map(addTemplateCard);

const elImg = imgPopup.querySelector("img");

function openPopupCardShow(cardData) {
  elImg.src = cardData.link;
  elImg.alt = cardData.name;
  titlePopup.textContent = cardData.name;
  showPopup(imgPopup);
}

profileForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fillProfile();
  hidePopup(popupEditProfile);
});


function activeLikeBtn(event) {
  const btn = event.target;
  btn.classList.toggle("element__like-button_active");
}

function deleteCard(event) {
  const card = event.target.closest(".element");
  card.remove();
}

function fillProfile() {
  profileName.textContent = profileNameInput.value;
  profileJob.textContent = profileJobInput.value;
}

function fillProfileInputs() {
  profileNameInput.value = profileName.textContent;
  profileJobInput.value = profileJob.textContent;
  showPopup(popupEditProfile);
}

popups.forEach((popup) => {
  const btnClose = popup.querySelector(".popup__close-button");
  btnClose.addEventListener("click", () => hidePopup(popup));
});

function showPopup(popup) {
  popup.classList.add(popupActiveClass);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", closeByEsc);
}

function hidePopup(popup) {
  popup.classList.remove(popupActiveClass);
  document.removeEventListener("keydown", closeByEsc);
}

const addCardButton = document.querySelector(".profile__add-button");
addCardButton.addEventListener("click", () => showPopup(popupAddCard));
editButton.addEventListener("click", fillProfileInputs);

function closeByEsc(event) {
  if (event.key === "Escape") {
    const popupOpened = document.querySelector(".popup_opened");
    hidePopup(popupOpened);
  }
}

popups.forEach((popup) => {
  popup.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.classList.contains(popupActiveClass)) {
      hidePopup(popup);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Получается ваша задача - при добавлении новой карточки сбрасывать состояние кнопки. Ваш код сейчас:

```
function addCard(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const cardName = typePlace.value;
  const cardLink = typeUrl.value;
  addTemplateCard({ name: cardName, link: cardLink });
  event.target.reset();
  hidePopup(popupAddCard);
  buttonPlace.disabled = true;
}
```

Здесь задаётся кнопке только состояние `buttonPlace.disabled = true`. Необходимо сюда же добавить и установку стиля неактивности.

```
function addCard(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const cardName = typePlace.value;
  const cardLink = typeUrl.value;
  addTemplateCard({ name: cardName, link: cardLink });
  event.target.reset();
  hidePopup(popupAddCard);
  buttonPlace.disabled = true;
  buttonPlace.classList.add('popup__save-button_disabled');
}
```

Но я бы советовал не устанавливать кнопке никакиз дополнительных классов для неактивности. В css можно навесить селектор на атрибут `disabled`:

```
.my-super-button[disabled] { ... }
```

И тогда не будет проблем с этим.